# Call function for everly key,value in dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Let's say we have a dict and specified function which takes two parameters as input

```
foo = {'key1':'value1', 'key2':'value2'}

def bar(key, value):
    print key, value
```

Is is possible to call this function for every key value pair in one liner?

I know that I can do it in list/dict comprehension but I think this solution is not pythonic cause I dont return anyting in **bar** function. Is there any recommended and pythonic way to do that?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: [bar(key, value) for key, value in foo.iteritems() if key is not None] but this is not intuitive case this is still a list

Answer (score 3):

Use a `for-loop` over the `.items` method of the dictionary:

```
for item in foo.items():
    bar(*item)
```

---

The `*` syntax unpacks the tuples (e.g. `('key1', 'value1')`) into the arguments to a function. Note that you could do the unpacking in the for-loop too:

```
for k, v in foo.items():
    bar(k, v)
```

---

Both of which give:

```
key2 value2
key1 value1
```

*You may notice that they are in a different order to the order you defined them in. This is just an implicit feature of dictionaries - they have no (reliable) order. The reason I say "reliable" is because it is deterministic (based on each object's hash, but it is unwise to rely on this.*

Answer (score 2):

yes, you can with a tiny modification to your function

```
foo = {'key1':'value1', 'key2':'value2'}

def bar(pair):
    key, value = pair
    print key, value
```

With this function at hand, you can use `map`.

```
map(bar, foo.items())
```

that produces:

```
key2 value2
key1 value1
```

Answer (score 1):

Quoting [PEP-20](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)

> Simple is better than complex.

Read the [Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/#id3)

Keeping things simple, you could do something like -

```
def bar(key, value):
    print key, value

for k, v in foo.items():
    bar(k, v)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foo = {'key1':'value1', 'key2':'value2'}

def bar(key, value):
    print key, value

[bar(key, value) for key,value in foo.items()]
```